# Display value of json to output

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Below is json code where i have o display its values. How to fetch the output as given below

```
 $jsondata = '{
                        "flowers": [
                            {
                                "id": "1",
                                "name": "Le Grand Bouquet Blanc",
                                "price": "65",
                                "currency": "euro"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "2",
                                "name": "Roses",
                                "price": "33",
                                "currency": "euro"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "3",
                                "name": "Mandarine",
                                "price": "125",
                                "currency": "euro"
                            }
                        ]
                    }';
```

Output should come like this

```
Name : Le Grand Bouquet Blanc, Price : 65
Name : Roses, Price : 33
Name : Mandarine, Price : 125
Total: 223 Euro
```

Any Help?

Comment: [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.json-decode.php) with the second argument `true` to get an array instead of an `std` object. After that it's a different story.

Comment: please explain with explanation

Comment: @Kirataka what did you tried ??

Comment: Mate, read the link I gave you. Look at the examples and learn some array functions. At least try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON decode, loop through the data and output the required text like so:

```
$data = json_decode($jsondata);                                                          

$total = 0;                                                                              
foreach($data->flowers as &$datum) {                                                     
    printf('Name : %s, Price: %d'.PHP_EOL, $datum->name, $datum->price);                 
    $total += $datum->price;                                                             
}                                                                                        
printf('Total: %d Euro'.PHP_EOL, $total);
```

Read up on some basic PHP functions/concepts:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: Thank you very much for not only providing answer but also the links.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `json_decode()` with `true` as second attribute to convert `JSON` it into `array` first.Then use `foreach` loop and get desired result.

```
<?php
 $jsondata = '{
                        "flowers": [
                            {
                                "id": "1",
                                "name": "Le Grand Bouquet Blanc",
                                "price": "65",
                                "currency": "euro"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "2",
                                "name": "Roses",
                                "price": "33",
                                "currency": "euro"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "3",
                                "name": "Mandarine",
                                "price": "125",
                                "currency": "euro"
                            }
                        ]
                    }';
$array = json_decode($jsondata,true);  
//print_r($array);
$sum = 0;
foreach($array['flowers'] as $flowers)
{
    echo "Name : ".$flowers['name'].",Price : ".$flowers['price'].PHP_EOL;
    $sum+=$flowers['price'];
    $currency = $flowers['currency'];
}
echo "Total:".$sum." ".$currency;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$jsondata = '{
                            "flowers": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1",
                                    "name": "Le Grand Bouquet Blanc",
                                    "price": "65",
                                    "currency": "euro"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "2",
                                    "name": "Roses",
                                    "price": "33",
                                    "currency": "euro"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "3",
                                    "name": "Mandarine",
                                    "price": "125",
                                    "currency": "euro"
                                }
                            ]
                        }';


    $data = json_decode($jsondata,true);

    echo "Name : "  . $data['flowers'][0]['name'] . ' , Price: ' . $data['flowers'][0]['price'] ;
```